# Cron Solaris 10

Tags: solaris

Is there an opportunity to write STDERR message to the /var/cron/log file when a job fails to execute? Or only the return codes can be written?

Answer (score 1):

I think the /var/cron/log is only used by cron itself, but you could redirect stderr into some other log file:

```
00 23 * * * /path/to/whatever 2>/some/log
```

Answer (score 1):

```
00 11 * * * /path_to_script 1>/output_file_name 2>/error_file_name
```

It will write standard output to /output_file_name and standard error to /error_file_name